# Using "group by"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The idea of my query is to extract the 6 sets of data based on the `line_id` which also is based on `enter_num` and `exit_num`.

Using the the query with the commented code provides me the result I need for 1 unique ID.
What I need are 6 results per ID. Is that possible?

I know `GROUP BY` is used to eliminate duplicates. But I want to get 6 results from each `line_ID`.

Code:

```
select * 
from 
  db_dn_us_icmlb_db1_202001.linecounting_records
where 
  line_id > 1
  and create_time between '2020-05-29 12:00' and '2020-06-01 12:25'
  and enter_num > 3
  and exit_num > 3
group by 
  line_id 
order by 
  enter_num + exit_num desc
```

results

```
Line_id  enter_num  Exit_num   Create_time        Update_time   
62       11         11         2020-06-01 08:55   2020-06-01 09:02   
88       4          15         2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:07   
74       9          7          2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:09   
76       9          7          2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:08   
75       6          9          2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:08
```

Expected results

```
Line_id  enter_num  Exit_num   Create_time        Update_time 
62       11         11         2020-06-01 08:55   2020-06-01 09:02   
62       4          15         2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:07   
62       9          7          2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:09   
62       9          7          2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:08   
62       6          9          2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:08
62       11         11         2020-06-01 08:55   2020-06-01 09:02   
72       4          15         2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:07   
72       9          7          2020-05-29 12:00   2020-05-29 12:09
```

and so on. The main point is that I want more values per "line_id"

Comment: Add code as text not as Image.

Comment: And use a plasuible table name

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate. For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Provide the source data, and the expected result, please.

Comment: We still don't have the source data, so we don't understand where the results came from. Please provide _all_ of the info requested. And we still don't understand why you want to get exactly 6 results per line ID. Will that become 100% clear from seeing the source data? If not, then please explain the reason, and also the rules by which you expect to choose these 6 lines. Thanks